# Spring XML Configuration and Namespaces

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration

I'm trying to configure a Spring config (xml) file and am trying to add a namespace for a valid schema file that I have living locally inside my project. The reason is that I don't have a "real" URL (web server, etc.), so I'm trying to just use a local schema that I will provide under `WEB-INF/`:

```
MyProject/
    src/
        java/
        config/
            MySchema.xsd
            spring-config.xml
    build.xml
```

Inside my `spring-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ms="http://myproject.org/MySchema.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
```

Project is building & deploying fine, but when I go to run it I get:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Failed to locate XSD resource '/META-INF/MySchema.xsd' on 
classpath. Namespace: 'http://myproject.org/MySchema.xsd'.
```

Ultimately I'd like both `spring-config.xml` and `MySchema.xsd` stored under `WEB-INF/`, so I'm not sure why Spring is looking inside `META-INF/`... any ideas?

The URL `http://myproject.org/MySchema.xsd` is not a real URL, just giving the schema its own namespace. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is SAX looking for the xsd in `META-INF`, not Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "definition" (I don't know the correct term) of the http://myproject.org/MySchema.xsd in the xsi:schemaLocation attribute.  Try something like this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
http://myproject.org/MySchema.xsd location/of/MySchema.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need define `spring.schemas` and `spring.handlers`?
See more here: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364131/Authoring-Custom-Namespaces-in-Spring-20

Answer (score 0):

You also need to define the [schema location](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#schemaLocation) for your `http://myproject.org/MySchema.xsd` [namespace](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp). From W3C, the schema location:

> consists of one or more pairs of URI references, separated by white space. The first member of each pair is a namespace name, and the second member of the pair is a hint describing where to find an appropriate schema document for that namespace. The presence of these hints does not require the processor to obtain or use the cited schema documents, and the processor is free to use other schemas obtained by any suitable means, or to use no schema at all.

I would use a different namespace name so as not to be confused with the namespace schema document hint. Maybe use a schema location such as `http://myproject.org/my-schema config/MySchema.xsd` instead.